# batch - run command through directory and sub-directory

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I'm writing a quick little batch script that will use ffmpeg to create gif's from short movie clips.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get it to run the ffmpeg commands in the for loop on any subfolders (and movies within them) . I was trying to use -r but that doesn't seem to work. I am pretty new to this, and I have kind of bashed my way through with this script. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
ECHO Movie Dir, please?
SET /p movdir=

IF EXIST "%movdir%" (
MKDIR "%movdir%\palgen"
MKDIR "%movdir%\gif"

FOR %%a in ("%movdir%\*.mov*") do (
"%ffmpeg%\ffmpeg" -i "%%a" -vf fps="%fps%",scale="%scale%":flags=lanczos,palettegen -y "%movdir%\palgen\%%~na.bmp"
"%ffmpeg%\ffmpeg" -i "%%a" -i "%movdir%\palgen\%%~na.bmp" -lavfi fps="%fps%",scale="%scale%":flags=lanczos,paletteuse -y "%movdir%\gif\%%~na.gif"
)

) ELSE (
ECHO That Directory doesn't exist, try again 
GOTO Start
)

RD /s /q "%movdir%\palgen"
ECHO All Done, bye :)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your code works for the single folder and `%ffmpeg%` is initalised, change the

```
FOR %%a in ("%movdir%\*.mov*") do (
```

to

```
FOR /r "%movdir%" %%a in ("*.mov") do (
```

Comment: that didn't seem to work, when I run the bat it closes instantly and nothing is created

Comment: Try the code now - I'd left in the `/d` switch by mistake.  The filespec is also *.mov to target only *.MOV files